# How can I retrieve a SQL variable from cfquery?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, coldfusion

I am running this inside of my `cfquery`.

```
SET @rID = ( SELECT TOP 1 roleid
             FROM Roles
             WHERE RoleName = @rName AND appid = @appID
             ORDER BY Created DESC);
```

Is it possible to retrieve `@rID` without having to run the `SELECT` query a second time?
As in:

```
<cfset varName = queryName.rID>
```

The above doesn't work obviously, but is there any other way to return the variable from the query?

Comment: I assume `SET @rID` is part of some larger operation, otherwise why couldn't you just select the value instead of setting it in a variable?

Comment: Correct, it's part of a larger operation. The entire thing is a multi-table insert. What I want is a simple statement that looks at 2 indexed columns and I could easily run it a second time, but I feel that would be redundant.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can get the value of `@rID` by `select`ing it without the need to run the full query again.

```
<cfquery name="qryRoleID">
    SET @rID = ( SELECT TOP 1 roleid
         FROM Roles
         WHERE RoleName = @rName AND appid = @appID
         ORDER BY Created DESC);
    SELECT @rID AS rID
</cfquery>
<cfdump var="#qryRoleID.rID#">
```